# Unable to install the 'evdev' python module in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, python-module

In Windows Visual Studio 2019 I'm trying to install the `evdev` python module. In the Python Environments tab there is a box that says "Packages (PyPl)" with a box underneath in which I entered "evdev". I then selected the choice "Install evdev (1.4.0)", and got the following error message.

```
----- Installing 'evdev==1.4.0' -----
Collecting evdev==1.4.0
  Using cached evdev-1.4.0.tar.gz (26 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for evdev, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: evdev
Running setup.py install for evdev: started
Running setup.py install for evdev: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ed_du\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ud4gsjiu\\evdev\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ed_du\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ud4gsjiu\\evdev\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ed_du\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vigd95a4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Include\evdev'
    cwd: C:\Users\ed_du\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ud4gsjiu\evdev\
Complete output (37 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\device.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\ecodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\eventio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\eventio_async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\events.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\evtest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\ff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\genecodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\uinput.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
copying evdev\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\evdev
running build_ext
running build_ecodes
The 'linux/input.h' and 'linux/input-event-codes.h' include files
are missing. You will have to install the kernel header files in
order to continue:

    yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
    apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
    emerge sys-kernel/linux-headers
    pacman -S kernel-headers

In case they are installed in a non-standard location, you may use
the '--evdev-headers' option to specify one or more colon-separated
paths. For example:

    python setup.py \
      build \
      build_ecodes --evdev-headers path/input.h:path/input-event-codes.h \
      build_ext --include-dirs  path/ \
      install
----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ed_du\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ud4gsjiu\\evdev\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ed_du\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ud4gsjiu\\evdev\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ed_du\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vigd95a4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Include\evdev' Check the logs for full command output.
     ----- Failed to install 'evdev==1.4.0' -----
```

Clearly the correct module was found, as the current version of evdev is 1.4.0. But it seems I need to install some linux kernel headers, and I don't know how to do that in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

After further research, I realized that `evdev` will not run in the Windows environment, but only Linux. As `evdev` exploits Linux kernel events, it works only on Linux and does not work on Windows or macOS.